# Continuous loading of localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, localhost

I've started to learn Gulp 4 yesterday, and I've got a problem already. When my project starts, a red block 200x200 should appear on the page, but nothing happens because localhost:3000 opens and never loads.

This is my `gulpfile.js`:

```js
   let gulp = require('gulp');
   let sass = require('gulp-sass');
   let pug = require('gulp-pug');
   let browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
   let uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
   let rename = require('gulp-rename');
   let autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

   gulp.task('browserSync', function(){
       browserSync.init({
           proxy: 'local.dev'
       })
   });

   gulp.task('sass', function() {
       return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.scss')
           .pipe(sass({pretty: true}))
           .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
           .pipe(autoprefixer())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
           .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
   });

   gulp.task('pug', function() {
       return gulp.src('app/pug/**/*.pug')
           .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('public/html'))
           .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
   });

   gulp.task('script', function() {
       return gulp.src('app/js/**/*.js')
           .pipe(uglify())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
           .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
   });

   gulp.task('watch', function() {
       gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.parallel('sass'))
       gulp.watch('app/pug/**/*.pug', gulp.parallel('pug'))
       gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', gulp.parallel('script'))
   });

   gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('script', 'sass', 'pug', 'browserSync', 'watch'));
```

This is `package.json`:

```js
{
  "name": "gulplanding",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-pug": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "ie >= 8",
    "edge >= 15",
    "ie_mob >= 10",
    "ff >= 45",
    "chrome >= 45",
    "safari >= 7",
    "opera >= 23",
    "ios >= 7",
    "android >= 4",
    "bb >= 10"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Vladislav Tokan",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I tried to use `server: {baseDir: 'public/'}` (I have 2 directories: "app" and "public") instead of `proxy: 'local.dev'`, I got an error "**Cannot GET /**".

How can I fix this continuous loading of localhost?

**UPDATE**: I fixed this problem. This worked for me:

```js
gulp.task('browserSync', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        server: 'public',
        startPath: '/html/index.html',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3001,
        open: true,
        tunnel: true
    })
});
```

Comment: dont use .dev - it was disabled for a long time. make binding to application.local or something, dont forget to update hosts file with 127.0.0.1 application.local

Comment: @PowerMouse It doesn't help, same problem. Permanent loading of localhost:3000.